# Magento Javascript issue with image resizing

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I'm using a Magento 1.4.1.1 install that I'm having issues with the javascript on a custom themed store.

For example, going to any product page (e.g. http://www.papakuraeducation.co.nz/index.php/teachers/magic-caterpillar-handwriting-casey-caterpillar-small-book.html) loads a Javascript file, which contains code which is supposed to scale down the .jpg file to fit the 'product-image' container it sits inside.

The relevent code seems to be around line #10279, which is causing a exception that $(imageEl).parentNode = null

```
Product.Zoom.prototype = {
    initialize: function(imageEl, trackEl, handleEl, zoomInEl, zoomOutEl, hintEl){
        this.containerEl = $(imageEl).parentNode;
        this.imageEl = $(imageEl);
        this.handleEl = $(handleEl);
        this.trackEl = $(trackEl);
        this.hintEl = $(hintEl);

(snipped...)
```

I've tried debugging it in Chrome and adding breakpoints, but tbh I'm not actually sure how to use this information to find the solution.

Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you using Simple Configurable Product extension?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an ID to the `<IMG>` in question. This ID should than be fed into the following code-space:

```
product_zoom = new Product.Zoom('IMAGE_ID', 'track', 'handle', 'zoom_in', 'zoom_out', 'track_hint');
```